# How to use putStringArrayListExtra(name, value) for adding extras to android intent.

Tags: android

I want to add multiple extras to my intent and retrive them.Is it possible with putStringArrayListExtra(name, value).

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do.. just like this..

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, New.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("list", value);
startActivity(i);
```

You should also make sure that ArrayList() holds only String Values..

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple extras in to putStringArrayListExtra as it is a map and retrive the lists by key name.